# How to describe the size of a file?

Tags: technical, computing

What should I say?

1. The file `foo.txt` is 350 kB.
2. The file `foo.txt` is 350 kB big.
3. The file `foo.txt` is 350 kB in size.
4. The file `foo.txt` has a size of 350 kB.
5. The file `foo.txt` measures 350 kB.
6. Something else?

I would prefer a reference to some reliable source if possible.

Comment: Just as we don't normally say *My car is red **in colour***, there's normally no need to explicitly clarify that *the file is 250Kb **in size*** (in fact, we usually just say ***it's a 350Mb file***). But this is really a matter for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), if it's anything other than proofreading.

Comment: I don't have an online source (thus a comment, not an answer), but I like to think I'm a reliable source: wrote my first program in 1980, have made a living as (exclusively) a software engineer since 1998.  The first ("... is 350 kB.") is the one I've run into most often - by far (and it's not even close).  Any of the five would be understandable, though.

Comment: @Ghotir: I've also been in software for many decades (not that we ever needed to refer to files that big back in the 80s! :). But the thing I find confusing about *all* of OP's examples is the capitalisation **kB** - that makes me think maybe the filesize is being specified in ***bits*** rather than ***bytes***, and I've never been too sure exactly how those are differentiated typograpgically.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, I noticed that too... something like "350 k" (or "350 meg") is more common in passing.  I was going to just assume the units were as desired, and aim at the "flavor text" around it.

Comment: @Ghotir: What with multi-terrabyte drives being the norm these days, perhaps it would be more logical to say *OP's file is a mere 350Kb **small***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the domain of static analysis, 350kB of code can be somewhat significant, as the analyses often take a lot of time. Small and large are relative notions :-) . Concerning the capitalization, `B` is Byte, `b` is bit (http://english.stackexchange.com/q/130279/66926). Also, colour is not a numeric property. A better comparison would be "this bridge *weighs* 500 tons and is 100m *long* and 20m *tall*", hence the desire to include some form of the term "size" or a technically more accurate equivalent (I do agree that "… in size" is awkward).

Comment: @Georges Dupéron: I don't know about that "better comparison". If we're just told it's a 200m bridge, we know that's the *width/span* by default anyway. And the whole issue of explicitly specifying the *dimension/metric* can only arise with the three spatial ones - if something is *X Kg, Y Mb, 20 ms...* we know without having to be told that these are values for *weight, datasize, (short) timescales...*

Comment: Unless there's reason for confusion (like you're discussing several different attributes of the file), #1 is the correct choice.  After that, #3 and #4.  The other two generally should not be used.

Comment: It sounds to be like you're just looking for a native speaker's take to proofread your material for you because you don't know what sounds natural in English. You may wish to explore our sister-site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The file size is 350KB** is the more appropriate one.  The more commonly used term is **'file size'**  than 'size of the file',  'measure of the file' or 'weight of the file'. The unit symbols are in block letters as follows:

[Kilobyte: KB, Megabyte: MB, Gigabyte: GB,  Terabyte: TB,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_size) etc.

> [NOTE](https://techterms.com/help/data_storage_units_of_measurement): "A lowercase "b" is used as an abbreviation for bits, while
>   an uppercase "B" represents bytes. This is an important distinction,
>   since a byte is 8x as large as a bit".

For example, 100 KB (kilobytes) = 800 Kb (kilobits).

[image]

Comment: I don't think the concept of electronic  file sizes existed in the 19th century... You can select the period you wish to cover in the boxes.